# textarea doesn't recognize data-id in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I've spent some time figuring out what goes wrong with `data-` attributes on textarea
I  can type `data-<anything>` and it will show when logging the `event.currenttarget`
All except `data-id` This doesn't show. Why is that?

```
 <Textarea
  value={itemValue || ""}                                                                                
  onChangeHandler={onChangeHandler}                                                                                
  readOnly={readOnly}                                                                              
  disabled={disabled}
  attributes={{                                                                                  
    "data-key": heading.key,                                                                                
    "data-id": dataId,                                                                            
    "data-banana": "banana",
    "data-one": 1
  }}
/>
```

logging `console.log(event.currentTarget);`
returns

```
<textarea class="textarea_textarea__209y7" data-key="textarea" data-banana="banana" data-one="1" data-required="false" style="height: 5rem;"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And then I've tried this:

```
<Textarea
  value={itemValue || ""}
  onChangeHandler={onChangeHandler}
  readOnly={readOnly}
  disabled={disabled}
  attributes={{
    "data-key": heading.key,
    "data-ID": dataId,
    "data-banana": "banana",
    "data-one": 1,
  }}
/>;
```

and it worked!

```
<textarea class="textarea_textarea__209y7" data-key="textarea" data-id="5" data-banana="banana" data-one="1" data-required="false" style="height: 5rem;"></textarea>
```

so capitalizing `id` did the work. Can someone explain why?